# .NET Unknown Hostname exception but nslookup works

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, hostname

I am writing a program that downloads FTP files with FluentFTP, but I get the following exception when trying to connect:

```
Host desconocido
en System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
en System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
en System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
en FluentFTP.FtpSocketStream.Connect(String host, Int32 port, FtpIpVersion ipVersions)
en FluentFTP.FtpClient.Connect(FtpSocketStream stream)
en FluentFTP.FtpClient.Connect()
```

However, when I do a ping to the same address and the same port, it works, and nsloopup can resolve the hostname. Any clue on why it doesn´t work?

Comment: Are you using the PC name or the IP address with Ping?  Try both.

Comment: It works with both

Comment: Why do you have three connect statements at the end?  I think only one is connecting and the other two are giving failures.

Comment: It´s a stack trace

Comment: When you instantiate FtpClient, are you sending the port number in the host string instead of as its own parameter? That would lead to the "No such host is known" error.

Comment: Show us your code. Make it clear, what exact value are you passing to "connect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the dumb mistake of instantiating FtpClient sending the port number in the host string instead of as its own parameter. Passing the port number like this worked:

```
using (var client = new FtpClient(host, port, userName, password)){
    //code
}
```